# "Process finished with exit code 1602" python

Tags: python

I'm new with python, I downloaded phycharm, I tried to run a very simple code like `print (5)` but I'm getting this error:

```
"C:\Computer Science python\python-3.6.0 (1).exe" "C:/Computer Science python/Practice python/First.py"
```

and

> Process finished with exit code 1602

Comment: this python install seems corrupt like hell. Please install python 3.6 from a valid source.

Comment: I downloaded python 3.6.0 from the [official website](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Comment: you sure you installed it? because it looks like you are trying to execute your code in the installer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python-3.6.0 (1).exe` is the downloaded setup executable archive (downloaded twice by Firefox :))

You're trying to run your script with the *installer*. You have to *install* python (using elevated privileges).

The error you're getting is a very good match to this error ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376931(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
 ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT 1602    The user cancels installation.
```

Once installed, you'll be able to run your script by clicking on it or by typing

```
"C:/Computer Science python/Practice python/First.py"
```

in a command prompt (.py associated to the python executable installed by default somewhere like `C:\python36`)